# NTP server syntax when applying to embedded devices

Tags: embedded, ntp

I have an embedded device which takes the time in the format of:

```
0.europe.pool.ntp.org
1.europe.pool.ntp.org
2.europe.pool.ntp.org
3.europe.pool.ntp.org
```

I asked the customer about an NTP server from their side as the solution is on-site, they gave me the NTP server as an IP only, since I have 4 fields and timezone on the embedded device, what is the practice of changing this IP to fit the NTP server format above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current list is a *server pool* - each one refers to a single NTP server.  For example if you ping each one for example:

```
> ping 3.europe.pool.ntp.org
Pinging 3.europe.pool.ntp.org [185.51.192.34] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 185.51.192.34: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=57
...

>ping 0.europe.pool.ntp.org

Pinging 0.europe.pool.ntp.org [91.121.7.182] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 91.121.7.182: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=55
...
```

Or perform a DNS look-up you will see that the each resolve to a different IP address.  Your local server is probably no different except that you have a pool of one.  You can probably simply place the single IP address where currently you define the pool.